# Material tabs in Rails 5 with Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, material-design, turbolinks

I want to make something like this: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Material-Design-Sliding-Tab-Menu-With-jQuery-CSS3/ as a menu in my Rails app. The slider's (underline) sliding animation should play and the page should load at the same time.

I managed to make the slider move under the link I clicked by setting menu to the data-turbolinks-permanent but the transition I set for the slider doesn't play - it just jumps. I also tried to use `jquery.animate` instead of the transition, but the animation is very delayed, slow and choppy. Is there any way to achieve this with Turbolinks?

```
  $('.menu-item').on 'click', () ->
    return if $(this).hasClass('slider')
    slider = $('.slider')
    slider.css('width', $(this).width())
    slider.css('left', $(this).offset().left - ($(window).width()-$('#wrapper').width())/2)
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul id="menu" data-turbolinks-permanent>
  <li class="menu-item underline"><%= link_to 'Item1', root_url %></li>
  <li class="menu-item underline"><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item underline"><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item underline"><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item underline"><a href="#">Item5</a></li>
  <li class="slider"></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS (Sass)

```
.slider
   display: block
   position: absolute
   bottom: 0
   left: 0
   height: 4px
   width: 90px
   background: black
   transition: all .3s linear
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use this great framework? materializecss.com/tabs.html

Anyways, if you really want to make those by yourself, place n number of tabs with a 100vw width side by side, and create n of elements in your header. Use jquery for sliding effect and pure id hrefing for onClick effect.